# Lazy loading: Object being loaded even though it is never referred to

Tags: c#, lazy-loading

I am using lazy loading to load information about the support ticket which a ticket message belongs to.
TicketMessage is the child of Ticket. In my TicketMessage class I have the following code to lazy load the Ticket object when the Ticket property of the TicketMessage object is referred to:

```
// Lazy loading of Ticket object
private Ticket _Ticket { get; set; }
public Ticket Ticket
{
    get
    {
        return this._Ticket ?? (this._Ticket = new Ticket(TicketID, ClientID, ConnectionString, Person.PersonID));
    }
}
```

However I am experiencing behaviour that indicates that this object is being every time the TicketMessage class is instantiated, thus resulting in some unwanted null reference exceptions. Is there anything blatantly wrong with my lazy loading pattern?

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside the getter and see who is calling it.

Comment: Looks ok (although a field would probably be enough for _Ticket instead of a property). Try setting a breakpoint in the getter and see where the stack trace takes you.

Comment: can you show the full class

Comment: I suppose the Person object is null in your code.

Comment: You are correct @OlegIgnatov, the Person object is null. But it is the Ticket object throwing the exception for some reason.

Comment: @lc It appears that the getter is never called..

Comment: What's the call stack on your exception?

Comment: @Rawling Here's the call stack:
Main
_nExecuteAssembly
RunUsersAssembly
RunInternal
Run
Run
ThreadStart

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say your NRE problem is more likely to be `Person` being null rather than an issue with the `null-coalescing` operation.

That being said, I don't particularly like the idea of doing an assignment in that way. From a readability point of view it would be much clearer written as:

```
private Ticket _ticket;
...
public Ticket Ticket
{
    get
    {
        if (this._ticket == null)
        {
            this._ticket = new Ticket(TicketID, ClientID, ConnectionString, Person.PersonID);
        }
        return this._ticket;
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you say that? Wouldn't the Person object be throwing the exception instead in that case?

Comment: @Maritim so, if `Person` is null the NRE would be thrown in the Ticket getter method, more specifically at the call to `new Ticket`.

Comment: But when stepping through the code it appears that the Ticket getter method of the TicketMessage class is never called.

Comment: @Maritim which line does the debugger flag up when the exception occurs? That usually indicates exactly which object is `null`.

Comment: string Sender = (ticketMsg.Direction == 2 ? this.Department.Name + " <" + this.Department.EmailAddress + ">" : ticketMsg.Person.FirstName + " " + ticketMsg.Person.LastName + " <" + ticketMsg.Person.EmailAddress + ">");

So it is indeed the Person object.

Comment: @Maritim well from that it could be 1 of 3 - `ticketMsg`/`Department` or `Person`. Best break pointing *before* the code hits and check yourself what is assigned & what isn't.

Comment: Neither Ticket nor Person is set. But in this particular scenario Direction is not equal to 2 and therefore the Ticket object is not being referred to. However the Person object is indeed being referred to, which leads me to believe that's where I should be focusing my effort.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make _Ticket as a property. Try this:

```
private Ticket _Ticket = null;

public Ticket Ticket
{
    get
    {
        return this._Ticket != null ? this._Ticket : (this._Ticket = new Ticket(TicketID, ClientID, ConnectionString, Person.PersonID));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue at the Person.PersonID call, you should be sure that this object is initialized.

The .Net 4 has a perfect class Lazy<>

```
private Lazy<Ticket> ticket = new Lazy<Ticket>(() => new Ticket(TicketID, ClientID, ConnectionString, Person.PersonID));

public Ticket Ticket
{
    get { return ticket.Value; }
}
```